# how can i get the a remote branch created by another user on my computer

Tags: git, github

I am trying to get the local branch by another user on my computer.

I have been trying some commands but none seems to be working. how can I fix this please? I also tried to merge them but there is no way I can do that.

I am trying to get the branch master which is created by another user and on the `git@github.com:oyerohabib/Eduo.git` repository

```
git remote -v 

my result

main    git@github.com:oyerohabib/Eduo.git (fetch)
main    git@github.com:oyerohabib/Eduo.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:matnex-mix/Eduo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:matnex-mix/Eduo.git (push)
```

Comment: git pull (git clone worst case scenario) is the command you are looking for. Next time, please try to include _the list of commands_ you tried and _the complete output_ of that.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Thanks I was able to solve the issue by chaining down my pull request. The answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using the command:

```
git pull "remote name" "name of the branch i wanted to pull"

E.g

git pull main habib **or**

git pull main malik **or**

git pull master kunle
```